# Rolling dice program

Tags: java, drjava

new to programming here. I am working on dice simulator project that is almost finished but I am having trouble adding a histogram that prints an asterisk equivalent to the frequency. I believe i need to use nested for loops but am getting very confused with the for loops i have created.The first outcome always seems to be correct but the rest are not. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class RollingDice{

   public static int getInt(Scanner scan) {
    int input;
    while ( !scan.hasNextInt() ) { 
      String garbage = scan.nextLine();
      System.out.println("Please enter an integer. ");
    }
    input = scan.nextInt();
    scan.nextLine();
    return input;
  }


public static void main(String [] args){

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
    Random rand = new Random();
    int dice1, dice2;
    int [] frequency = new int [13];
    int [] rolls = new int [13];
    String stars = ""; 
    double percentage; 
    System.out.println("Enter the number of trials:"); 
    int n = getInt(scan); 


    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        dice1 = rand.nextInt(6)+1; 
        dice2 = rand.nextInt(6)+1;
        frequency[dice1+dice2]++;

    }


    System.out.printf("Outcome\tFrequency\tPercentage\tHistogram\n");
    for (int i = 2; i < frequency.length; i++) {
      for ( int j = 0; j < frequency[i]; j++) {
        stars = stars + "*"; 
      }
         percentage = (frequency[i] * 100.0) / n;

         System.out.printf("%7d\t%6d\t%10.2f\t%s\n",i,frequency[i], percentage, stars);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please give the output you have, and the diffenrence with the expected output

Answer (score 1):

You just forgot to reset the `stars` variable before iterate on the counting **:**

```
for (int i = 2; i < frequency.length; i++) {
    stars = "";
    for ( int j = 0; j < frequency[i]; j++) {
        stars = stars + "*"; 
    }
    percentage = (frequency[i] * 100.0) / n;

    System.out.printf("%7d\t%9d\t%10.2f\t%s\n",i,frequency[i], percentage, stars);
}
```

Also `%6d` should be `%9d` as *Frequency* is 9-length